# Mostrar contenido de un objeto Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

** Sugerir un mejor titulo si es necesario **
Estoy trabajando en Vue, quiero lograr mostrar un contenido, solo si este tiene el mismo valor que un `array`

Tengo dos arrays, uno llamado "`typesArticle`" y otro `array` llamado `articles` con varios objetos, de la siguiente forma:

```
typesArticle: ['Handguns', 'Assault Rifles', 'Sub-Fusil', 'Snipers', 'Shotguns'],
        articles: [{
                name: 'AEK-971',
                type: 'Assault Rifles',
                typeAmmon: 5.56,
                firerate: 900
            },
            {
                name: 'MP5',
                type: 'Sub-Fusil',
                typeAmmon: 9,
                firerate: 700
            }, {
                name: 'Glock 18C',
                type: 'Handguns',
                typeAmmon: 9,
                firerate: 1100
            }, {
                name: 'Barret .50',
                type: 'Snipers',
                typeAmmon: .50,
                firerate: 'Semi-Automatico'
            }, {
                name: 'Saiga 12K',
                type: 'Shotguns',
                typeAmmon: .12,
                firerate: 'Semi-automatico'
            }
        ]
```

En mi html tengo de esta forma una estructura:

```
<h2>Assault Rifles</h2>
    <p>{{Solo Rifles}}</p>
 <br>
<h2>Handguns</h2>
    <p>{{Solo pistolas}}</p>
```

Lo que quiero lograr, realizar una condicion supongo que debe lograrse perfectamente desde la directiva `v-if` Que lo que debe hacer, es recibir cada articulo y verificar que la propiedad type del objeto se encuentre en el array de type, y asi imprimirlo el nombre del articulo en su respectiva seccion o grupo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `filterArticles()` toma al array `typesArticle` y le aplica un `reduce` guardando en un objeto cada item del array `typesArticle` como una propiedad del objeto `filteredArticles`, cada propiedad contiene un `array` dependiendo de la función `filter` aplicada en el array `articles` donde aplica el filtro que si el actual item de `typesArticle` es igual a la propiedad `type` de cada objeto del array `articles` entonces filtra un `array` con la coincidencia mencionada.

Luego en el template se itera el objeto `filteredArticles` tomando sus `keys` que están representadas como propiedades de este objeto y por cada objeto(que por valor tienen un `array` de objetos filtrados) se vuelve a iterar este `array` de objetos indicando su `name` & `type`.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    typesArticle: [
      "Handguns",
      "Assault Rifles",
      "Sub-Fusil",
      "Snipers",
      "Shotguns"
    ],
    articles: [
      {
        name: "AEK-971",
        type: "Assault Rifles",
        typeAmmon: 5.56,
        firerate: 900
      },
      {
        name: "MP5",
        type: "Sub-Fusil",
        typeAmmon: 9,
        firerate: 700
      },
      {
        name: "Glock 18C",
        type: "Handguns",
        typeAmmon: 9,
        firerate: 1100
      },
      {
        name: "Barret .50",
        type: "Snipers",
        typeAmmon: 0.5,
        firerate: "Semi-Automatico"
      },
      {
        name: "Saiga 12K",
        type: "Shotguns",
        typeAmmon: 0.12,
        firerate: "Semi-automatico"
      }      
    ],
    filteredArticles: {}
  },
  mounted() {
    this.filterArticles();
  },
  methods: {
    filterArticles() {
      this.filteredArticles = this.typesArticle.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item] = this.articles.filter(a => a.type === item);
        return acc;
      }, {});
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(article, key) in filteredArticles" :key="key">
        <h2>{{ key }}</h2>
        <div v-for="(a, index) in article" :key="index">
          <p>name: {{ a.name }}</p>
          <p>type: {{ a.type }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre style="background-color: #efefef">
      filteredArticles: {{ filteredArticles }}
    </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Aunque propones hacerlo a través de la directiva `v-if`, propongo mejor dejar el filtrado de datos a través de una [Propiedad calculada](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)
- Al pasar la lógica de programación a una *computed property* dejamos *ligera* la vista
- Recorremos los elementos de `articles` para después con un condicional para verificar si el objeto `ele` en la propiedad `type` es igual a una posición específica del array indexado `typesArticle`
- A falta de una mejor opción, le indico en el condicional que evalúe si `ele.type` es igual a la posición 0 o 1 del array `typesArticle` según cada caso solicitado
- En la vista solo itero los resultados devueltos por cada una de las propiedades computadas con un `v-for` e imprimiendo la propiedad `nombre`

**Código**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Filtro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
      Armas de tipo rifles
      <ul>
         <li v-for="article in filterRifles">{{ article.name }}</li>
      </ul>
      Armas de tipo pistola
      <ul>
        <li v-for="article in filterHandgun">{{ article.name }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script>
        let app = new Vue({
          el: `#app`,
          data:{
                typesArticle: ['Handguns', 'Assault Rifles', 'Sub-Fusil', 'Snipers', 'Shotguns'],
                articles: [{
                        name: 'AEK-971',
                        type: 'Assault Rifles',
                        typeAmmon: 5.56,
                        firerate: 900
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'MP5',
                        type: 'Sub-Fusil',
                        typeAmmon: 9,
                        firerate: 700
                    }, {
                        name: 'Glock 18C',
                        type: 'Handguns',
                        typeAmmon: 9,
                        firerate: 1100
                    }, {
                        name: 'Barret .50',
                        type: 'Snipers',
                        typeAmmon: .50,
                        firerate: 'Semi-Automatico'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Saiga 12K',
                        type: 'Shotguns',
                        typeAmmon: .12,
                        firerate: 'Semi-automatico'
                    }
            ]
          },
          computed: {
            filterRifles() {
              return this.articles.filter(ele => {
                if(ele.type === this.typesArticle[1]){
                  return ele
                }
              })
            },
            filterHandgun() {
              return this.articles.filter(ele2 => {
                if(ele2.type === this.typesArticle[0]){
                  return ele2
                }
              })
            }
          }
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```